# How to run group of commands in parallel followed by an other command

Tags: bash

I want to execute `cmdA`, `cmdB` and `cmdC` in parallel before `cmdD`. This is what I have so far:

```
$> (cmdA & cmdB & cmdC) && cmdD
```

As long as `cmdC` finished last this works, but, for example, if `cmdC` finishes first, `cmdD` is executed right away. So, my question is, how can I wait for all three commands befofe executing `cmdD`? Is this possible with just `&&` and `&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I **wait** for all three commands befofe executing cmdD?

Use `wait`.

```
(cmdA & cmdB & cmdC ; wait) ; cmdD
```